# Java client connectivity issue - OPC DA

Tags: java, opc, dcom

Recent Microsoft patch has broken our Java client connectivity to OPC server. Microsoft raised Authentication level to Packet Integrity. we are using Utgard java OPC library to connect to OPC server which internally uses Jinterop java based COM library. with the patch Our client is not able to add subscription groups to listen to the data changes on the OPC server. We couldn't find where in the library the authentication level is configured. if we can configure it ti DEFAULT the issue will be resolved.

Please let me know if you have any pointers on this.

```
JISession session = JISession.createSession(ipAddress,userName,pasword);
JIComServer  comServer = new JIComServer(JIClassId.valueOf(classId), address, session);
IJIComObject instance = comServer.createInstance();
IJIComObject opcServer = new OPCServer(instance);
//after we will create access base groups and add them to the server, during attaching handler it is failing.
```

ERROR
*JIException: The RPC server is unavailable. Please check if the COM server is up and running and that route to the COM Server is accessible (A simple "Ping" to the Server machine would do). Also please confirm if the Windows Firewall is not blocking DCOM access. [0x800706BA]
`at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.call(JIComServer.java:1004) at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.call(JIComServer.java:951) at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComObjectImpl.call(JIComObjectImpl.java:293) at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComObjectImpl.call(JIComObjectImpl.java:159) at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIFrameworkHelper.attachEventHandler(JIFrameworkHelper.java:285) at org.openscada.opc.dcom.da.impl.OPCGroupStateMgt.attach(OPCGroupStateMgt.java:179)`
*